# flutter project Build error - firebase_messaging-9.1.4 import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

Tags: firebase, flutter

firebase_messaging-9.1.4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");

Screenshot attached - https://ibb.co/mc0Hhvy

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'
 flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3
  http: ^0.13.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.0
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^2.3.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  recase: ^3.0.1
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+1
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^18.4.42
  crypto: ^2.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  flutter_user_agent: ^1.2.2
  flutter_ip: ^0.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.8
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded to **firebase_messaging: ^10.0.1** and it worked